# running unix like command "./a.out <data.txt" in windows environment on c++ file

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

How do I run a command like interface on windows and use the g++ and ./a.out

I am a beginning programmer used to using putty/ssh to write (nano), compile (g++ command), and run (./a.out) c++ programs.

Our class has now switched to netbeans, but our latest assignment requires us to use the `./a.out <datafile.txt`-like command.

Or is the input redirection style `./a.out <data.txt` unique to unix and cannot be done in windows?

edit: the `<` input redirection marks made my post mostly unreadable. Sorry about that

2nd edit: There is actually a terminal built into netbeans that VERY conveniently starts in your project directory. open it in netbeans by selecting Window -> output -> Terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows.

Comment: If you need to use a Cygwin program to read or write a file located outside of c:\cygwin, you can use a pathname beginning with /cygdrive/c/ for this purpose. -- This helped me. Maybe others will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

start,
run,
cmd,
cd directory,
g++ a.cpp,
a.exe

Comment: How do I make cmd recognize g++?
C:\Users\...\Documents\NetBeansProjects>g++ main.cpp
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: in windows 7 hit start, type PATH, click edit the system environment variables, click "environment variables", under system variables you'll see PATH, and then add ;c:\mingw\bin (assuming you're using mingw)...no need for CYGWIN.

Answer (score 0):

Windows includes `.` in `$PATH`, so the `./` at the beginning is superfluous (and wrong, since it would be `.\`). The rest is the same.